# How to overlay an icon on an image in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, user-interface, dart

I have a Staggered GridView that is as given below. In every item of the grid I'm trying to place an Icon in it's center, overlaying on top of the image. I tried using a Stack but the Icon seems displaced.

This is my code:

```
Scaffold(
          body: Align(
            alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
            child: StaggeredGridView.countBuilder(
              crossAxisCount: 4,
              itemCount: 8,
              itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                return Container(
                  child: ClipRRect(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(6)),
                    child: Image.network(
                      'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1534361960057-19889db9621e?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=800&q=60',
                      fit: BoxFit.fitHeight,
                    ),
                  ),
                );
              },
              staggeredTileBuilder: (int index) =>
                  new StaggeredTile.count(2, index.isEven ? 2 : 3),
              mainAxisSpacing: 4.0,
              crossAxisSpacing: 4.0,
            ),
          ),
        );
```

and this is what the result looks like:
[image]

And this is what I've been trying to achieve:
[image]

Comment: Have you tried using a Positioned widget inside a Stack?

Comment: Yes I tried using stack but it wasn’t getting aligned properly in the center.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You used the correct widget `Stack` but maybe you missed something.
I wrapped the `Container` by `Stack` with `fit: StackFit.expand,` to fill all the space, and the `Positioned` will be in the center
So here the full code and it might help:

```
Scaffold(
              body: Align(
                alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
                child: StaggeredGridView.countBuilder(
                  crossAxisCount: 4,
                  itemCount: 8,
                  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                    return Stack(
                      fit: StackFit.expand,
                      children: [
                        Container(
                          child: ClipRRect(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(6)),
                            child: Image.network(
                              'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1534361960057-19889db9621e?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=800&q=60',
                              fit: BoxFit.fitHeight,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                        Positioned(child: Icon(Icons.play_arrow))
                      ],
                    );
                  },
                  staggeredTileBuilder: (int index) =>
                  new StaggeredTile.count(2, index.isEven ? 2 : 3),
                  mainAxisSpacing: 4.0,
                  crossAxisSpacing: 4.0,
                ),
              ),
            )
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the Stack widget with an alignment property of center.

```
child: Stack(
  alignment: Alignment.center,
  children: <Widget>[
     //Image
     //Icon
  ],
),
```

Comment: Tried this but the items are getting displaced in the Staggered Grid.

Comment: Maybe try using your image in decoration: BoxDecoration(image: DecorationImage()) and the icon as the child of the container.